# tmux change status background for session only

Tags: tmux

I want to create two tmux sessions with different status line background color.

In terminal A I do:

```
tmux
tmux set status-bg colour166
```

In terminal B I do:

```
tmux
tmux set status-bg colour16
```

afterwards both tmux sessions have colour16. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in -bg/-fg to -style mapping. Use "tmux set status-style bg=colour166" instead.